# Offset Fetch Next to get all rows

Tags: paging, sql-server-2012

I have a query in SQL Server 2012 that should get back a number of records based on the page size I specify and the page it is on.  It looks like this:

```
SELECT LocID, LocName
FROM Locations
ORDER BY LocName OFFSET @PageNum ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

The code is pretty simple.  What I need to do, though, is put that into a function to return the paging correctly.  However, I could also be needing all records back from this function, so I need to have the option of calling the function without any OFFSET or FETCH (mostly, this is for a report that has no paging and should only be the straight data).  I can't think of a good way to do this.

Comment: Why not just call it with a `@PageSize` big enough to return all records?

Comment: The problem is, I don't know how big the record set is going to be until after I've run it.  I had another question about something similar to that problem as well.

Comment: Upper bound of INT or BIGINT should be sufficient, depending...

Comment: @CrystalBlue - I agree with Aaron. Your server/network/client will definitely timeout before you come anywhere near the amount of records that can be returned by specifying the upper bound of an int.

Comment: I understand that this is a valid tactic right now (I've set the page size to around a million records for now) and that solves my dilemma.  But is that the answer to my question: there is no way of doing what I want to do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could say:

```
@PageNum  INT,
@PageSize INT

...

SELECT @PageSize = COALESCE(@PageSize, 2000000000);   
-- 2 billion should be enough?

... OFFSET (COALESCE(@PageNum, 1)-1)*@PageSize ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

When you just want all rows, pass in NULL to both parameters.

Comment: This is what I've been suggested to do by other people for now, so this seems like the most valid answer.  Thanks!

Comment: When I pass NULL to both parameters, I get the following error: The number of rows provided for a TOP or FETCH clauses row count parameter must be an integer.

Comment: @MeyssamToluie So stop passing NULL or use COALESCE to establish defaults.